# jQuery Event not triggering when written in code but triggers if written in Console

Tags: jquery

It works correctly if I Write the same jQuery Function in console

My Html

```
<input type="radio" name="a" class="rad" value="Option 1"/>Option 1
<input type="radio" name="a" class="rad" value="Option 2"/>Option 2
```

My jQuery Function

```
$('.rad').on('change',function(){
    console.log('Radio clicked');
});
```

Comment: Assuming you have your code in a `$(document).ready(fn);` code block, there's no reason this should not work: https://jsfiddle.net/pk4htk9y/. Try checking the console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because either element is not loaded when you are trying to attach the event or you have error in code which do not call this script.

In case one, You need to either write the script at the end of body or wrap it in dom ready event:

```
$(function(){
$('.rad').on('change',function(){
 console.log('Radio clicked');
});});
```

Comment: Still the same error, Adding the code in DOM did not change anything.

Comment: No errors in console, the event itself is not getting triggered, Anything written inside the function is not at all getting executed.

Comment: @VishnuYS: can you reproduce this in fiddle.

Comment: @openandfree So just sounds like these elements are added dynamically to the DOM. This (delegating event to document level) would work then: `$(document).on('change', '.rad', function(){
 console.log('Radio clicked');
});`

Comment: @openandfree: is it correct what A.Wolff is saying?

Comment: Yeah, Its working in fiddle. Not on my local machine.

Comment: @VishnuYS BUT is that dynamic elements or not? If not maybe you just have browser cache issue, who knows???

Comment: Yes Milind Sir!  @VishnuYS It seems you generates those elements dynamically. please go through this link : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Please write your code in

```
document.ready(function(){
})
```

It will surely work